# Issue - FullCalendar not fully rendered on load using tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I have injected the FullCalendar in a jquery ui tab. But the issue is the tab is loading with only header items like prev next and today button and if you notice i have added eventAfterAllRender() to check all items are rendered or not as the issue persists the alert **doesnot** come up.

I believe some issue in calling the code but weirdly when i click on today or prev or next buttons or resize the browser the calendar loads up fine with all values correctly and then the alert fires.

Here is my code sample:

### HTML

```
<div id="call-detail-tab">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#call-detail-tab-1">Call Information</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="call-detail-tab-1">
                        <div id='calendar'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

### Js

```
    $('#call-detail-tab').tabs();
    ....
    ...
    $('#call-detail-tab').show();
.....

var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'next'
            },
            dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                if (allDay) {
                    alert('Clicked on the entire day: ' + date);
                }else{
                    alert('Clicked on the slot: ' + date);
                }
                alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
                alert('Current view: ' + view.name);
                // change the day's background color just for fun
                $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
            },
            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
                alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
                alert('View: ' + view.name);
                // change the border color just for fun
                $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
            },
            eventAfterAllRender: function( view ) { 
                alert('All Items Rendered!');
            },
            eventBackgroundColor: '#C7E89B',
            eventBorderColor: '#E4FCA7',
            eventTextColor: '#000000',
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                    end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                    url: 'http://google.com/'
                }
            ],
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                 element.bind('dblclick', function() {
                         alert('double click!');
                 });
                 // alert shows up in linux chrome, but messes up draggable
            },
            windowResize: function(view) {
                   alert('The calendar has adjusted to a window resize');
            },
            height: calcCalendarHeight()
        });

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'aspectRatio', 1.80);

    //}

     function calcCalendarHeight() {
         var h = $(window).height() - 400;
         return h;
     }
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Might have something to do with Jquery versions

Comment: No i am using now 1.10.2 version for jquery but no effect

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/6wE8v/465/

On latest CDN of full calendar http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/download/

and Jquery version 1.8.3 and Jquery UI 1.9.2

basically same code

```
<div id="call-detail-tab">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#call-detail-tab-1">Call Information</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="call-detail-tab-1">
                     <div id="mycalendar"></div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that should mean JS execution before the tab/fullcalendar script is messing things up. Have you installed firebug and verified the errors?